# Get static properties from struct type

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to list all static properties from struct type. I don't make instances of this struct - it's used as a type.

What I need is list all properties from this struct (from struct not from instance of this struct). Is this possible?

So something like:

CommUser.GetType.GetProperties();

My struct:

```
public struct CommUser
{
   public static string pcUSER_URI_R97 {get;set;}        
   public static string pcUSER_URI_R98 {get;set;}   
}
```

Comment: Hint: `type.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Static )`.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly had it

```
var names = typeof(CommUser).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public)
                            .Select(x => x.Name);    
foreach (var name in names)
    Console.WriteLine(name);
```

**Output**

```
pcUSER_URI_R97
pcUSER_URI_R98
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/bU10Ng)

---

**Additional Resources**

[typeof (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof)

> Used to obtain the System.Type object for a type

[GetProperties(BindingFlags)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetProperties_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_)

> When overridden in a derived class, searches for the properties of the
>   current Type, using the specified binding constraints.

[BindingFlags Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> - `Public` Specifies that public members are to be included in the search
> - `Static` Specifies that static members are to be included in the search.

Comment: Fanastic answer :) Perhaps you know how to call the property, once you found it? I have a fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QSlvZu

Comment: @FrenkyB of course I do however this is another question ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704907/how-to-call-static-method-once-you-found-it-on-struct-type