# How to call static method once you found it on struct type

Tags: c#, .net

I have a struct with static properties (I don't make instances of that struct, I am using it like a type - CommUser.MyProperty).

I've written a method for finding property by name. What I don't know is how to call that property, once it's found? Something like: `CommUser.item` (item is found property).

```
public struct CommUser
{
    public static string pcUSER_URI_R97
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static string pcUSER_URI_R98
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public bool CheckIfUserHasRights(string[] listUserRights)
{
    var listUserProperties = typeof(CommUser).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

    foreach (var item in listUserProperties)
    {
        foreach (var usrRight in listUserRights)
        {
            if (item != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(usrRight))
            {
                if (item.Name.EndsWith(usrRight))
                {
                    //how to make a call to CommUser.item ?                         
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `item.GetValue(null)` should get the value of a static property `item`, however: I suspect that your struct is simply *incorrect* right now - a struct with 2 static properties and nothing else sounds **very** wrong

Comment: My struct is CommUser. I don't have instance of this struct. I use it like type.

Comment: @MarcGravell - I have hundreds of properties on that struct. I've showed two of them just to simplify question.

Comment: @MichaelRandall the properties are `static`, so: that doesn't apply; *why* they are `static` is anyone's guess - my personal guess is "they shouldn't be"

Comment: @FrenkyB and the other properties aren't all `static`? note: there are two things that are *usually* wrong when I see them in folks' code... the first is `static` mutable properties, and the second is `struct` - *any* `struct` (don't get me wrong: there are valid and great uses of `struct`, but most times I see them: people are using them inappropriately). Top tip: if you can use up to date compiler versions, declare your `struct` as `readonly struct`. If it still compiles (perhaps with minor tweaks): you might be using it correctly.

Comment: @FrenkyB, why struct instead of a static class? On the other hand, I feel that there is something wrong with the design when the reflection is used in this kind of manner to access properties.

Comment: `(string)typeof(CommUser).GetProperty("pc" + usrRight).GetValue(null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `item.GetValue(null)`. The argument is the instance, but you don't have one for static properties, obviously.